# How do we get a blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

Many other sites have [blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs). How can we get a blog?

Comment: Relevant: [Does our site need a blog like a few sites on the network have?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4129/264)

Comment: If you look at the page you yourself linked, you'll find a link to [the answer](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

Answer (score 8):

From [the Stack Exchange blog post about the community blog initiative](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/):

> ### So how does my site get a community blog?
>
> Starting a blog is easy.  Keeping up a blog, contributing to it regularly is difficult. Blogs are hard work.  Wanting a blog is obviously the first step, but there are a few things that the community needs to discuss in order to get a blog going.
>
> 1. **Raise the idea on the child meta.** A community blog needs the involvement of community members.  These blogs don’t exist to be the personal blog of a community member.  They are both for and run by the community.  It needs to be something the community collectively wants and will cultivate.
> 2. **Define the scope and purpose of the blog.** Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic? Is it about the industry around the topic? Keep in mind the audience of your community and their interests. Another generic blog about <x> may not be all that interesting.  A community blog should be interesting to both current members and potential new members.
> 3. **Recruit contributors.** Who will write entries for the blog? Starting a blog is a bit like going through the buffet line. Be realistic – don’t let your eyes be bigger than your stomach. Think seriously about if and how often you will be able to contribute a blog post, including research/prep time.  The more contributors there are, the less frequently each contributor needs to post.  One post a month is a much easier to stomach than a couple posts every week.
> 4. **Plan a schedule.** Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a week, posted Mondays? Will there be <x> posts on Tuesdays and <y> posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but you should post at least once a week.
>
> ...
>
> When a new blog is setup for a community, it will go through a beta phase much like the Q&A site.  Initially, the blog will be hosted on our *.blogoverflow.com network.  As the blog matures, grows, and continues to be contributed to regularly, we will move the blog over to our blog.*.stackexchange.com network and replace the blog link on the Q&A site to the official community blog for the site.